# Regex not substituting string with spaces

Tags: python, regex

i have made this code to replace all the non alphabet with the space but i am not getting the spaces doing this is clearing all the spaces

```
edit = [["this, is sample 1."],["this!is @ sample two.*"]]
def clearpunch(sentence):
    clean = re.sub(r"'|\W|\d|_",r" ",sentence)
    return clean
edit = edit.map(clearpunch)
edit
```

getting text like this
"[["thisissample"], ["thisissampletwo"]]"

and i want a text like
"[["this  is sample    "], ["this is   sample two  "]]"

Comment: The function seems fine. What is `edit`?

Comment: what does ```edit``` mean?

Comment: Just a ```re.sub(r"'|\W|\d|_",r" ",sentence)``` will return you what you want, what are you expecting more than that?

Comment: edit is a list of list of many sample texts eg

Comment: Make this a running script that demonstrates the problem. We should be able to copy, run and see what you see.

Comment: The **regex** and substitution is fine, and works as expected

Comment: @YatinKumar ```map``` is not a method, it's a function. you should've used it like this ```edit = map(clearpunch, edit)```

Comment: Now your first line has syntax errors.

Comment: ok i have used map like u suggested but it wasn't the problem

Comment: am i sorry it was a typo i think its ok now

Comment: Try running this exact script. You'll first find that you need to `import re`. Then you'll find that `'list' object has no attribute 'map'`, then you'll find out you are passing in a list of lists, so that `sentence` is really a list of sentences. Its important to get the example running so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you what you want, using the map function:

```py
import re

def clearpunch(sentence):
    clean = re.sub(r"'|\W|\d|_",r" ",sentence)
    return clean

edit = [["this, is sample 1."],["this!is @ sample two.*"]]

answer = [list(map(clearpunch, item)) for item in edit]

print(answer)
```

Input:

```
[["this, is sample 1."],["this!is @ sample two.*"]]
```

Output:

```
[['this  is sample   '], ['this is   sample two  ']]
```

If you just want lowercase English letters you can use this regex pattern: `r"[^a-z]"`